# Rotating and cropping images

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms

I am building a website that will allow the administrator to upload images to use in a slideshow. I would like to allow the user to rotate and or crop the image then save over the original file. I am not sure how to do so.

So far I have tried to tackle the rotating of the images, for which I have tried the following code but it does not seem to do anything. What am I missing?

Code behind

```
protected void btnRotate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String path = Server.MapPath(piccy.ImageUrl);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
    img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    img.Save(path);

}
```

my aspx

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="piccy" ImageUrl="~/pic1.jpg" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnRotate" runat="server" OnClick="btnRotate_Click" Text="Rotate Right" />
```

This is all I could come up with on my own and it doesn't rotate them at all, what am I missing? Probably a lot.
With regard to the cropping I don't even know where to start

If anyone is able to help I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Can you confirm it is really loading the correct image? For starts I would try saving it under a different name.

Comment: Just to say, you should probably be disposing of img

Comment: @TheLethalCoder how would I go about disposing of the image?

Comment: @M_Griffiths I doubt it'll help with the rotation problem but otherwise the image stays alive in memory, you should be doing using (Image img = Image.FromFile(path)) { //do stuff with img } or img.Dispose(); once you're finished with it

Comment: @BojanBjelic when I save under a different name the image appears in the website directory as it should

Comment: @M_Griffiths I ran your code in a simple console app, loading an image, rotating and saving (to a different path and the same path) and it worked, so I don't think the problem is with the code you've posted

Comment: @M_Griffiths Have you checked the code actually gets run in the button click event?

Comment: Its rotating the image, from what I can see in the file system. But it is not showing the rotation in the browser. And yes it gets run ;)

Comment: @M_Griffiths if the image is changed, but not in the browser have you tried repainting the control that displays the image. i.e. .Invalidate() or .Refresh() or just reloading the image in?

Comment: Your browser is caching the image and doesn't think it's changed. Either save the image under a new name or use a querystring time-hack to fool the browser. But yes as TheLethalCoder says, are you refreshing the page/UpdatePanel first?

Comment: no how would I do so?

Comment: I added  img.Dispose();  piccy.ImageUrl = path; to the end but when it reloads the imageurl the image disappears

Comment: @M_Griffiths You shouldn't dispose of it until you're finished using it

Comment: Managed to get it sorted, thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, seems the image file is locked.

Try

1. create a temporary copy of the image,
2. apply the transformation on that, and then
3. overwrite the original.